# Testing the Mac Installer Package using Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6, osx-yosemite, mac-app-store

Before submitting my Mac App to the App Store I am used to test the installation package following
the procedure described here:

[Testing the Mac Installer Package - Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW40)

This mainly involve archiving the app, exporting as Mac Installer Package and installing it using:

```
sudo installer -store -pkg .... -target /
```

Since I updated to Xcode 6 I always get a signature error when I start the app [EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)]:

```
Process:               ......... [1749]
Path:                  /Applications/.........
Identifier:            ......
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           .......... [1749]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-11-07 18:52:45.292 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        142A2C49-B327-E26A-0DE4-0CCB99AC1DC0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       174FDF51-B783-4172-952B-EB8E5B07D436

Time Awake Since Boot: 2700 seconds
Time Since Wake:       690 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0x7fff75cbe0a8 (cr2):
    __LINKEDIT             00007fff68263000-00007fff68277000 [   80K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> Submap                 00007fff70000000-00007fff80000000 [256.0M] r--/rwx SM=PRV  process-only VM submap
    unused shlib __DATA    00007fff749e7000-00007fff76f76000 [ 37.6M] rw-/rw- SM=COW  system shared lib __DATA not used by this process

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff681f4000 _dyld_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000d  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007fff556dcb50
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff681f4000  rfl: 0x0000000000000201  cr2: 0x00007fff75cbe0a8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000f4
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
    0x7fff681f3000 -     0x7fff68229837  dyld (???) <4696A982-1500-34EC-9777-1EF7A03E2659> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1226
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=300K resident=288K(96%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=12K(4%)
Writable regions: Total=8420K written=0K(0%) resident=12K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%)     unallocated=8408K(100%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)                4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                              228K
__LINKEDIT                           80K
__TEXT                              220K
mapped file                        1044K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                              65.6M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     65.5M


Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM MBP111.0138.B11, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.16f68
Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.124.12.8)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0f10 14890, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500.28 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2
```

Exactly the same app as not this problem using Xcode 5.

Any suggestion?

This is getting me crazy since I am not confident to submit the app to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually contacted Apple support and they answered that the procedure is:

```
1) Export your app as a Mac Application

2) productbuild --component <APP>.app /Applications <APP>.pkg --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer:"

3) sudo installer -store -pkg <APP>.pkg -target /
```

The documentation doesn't mention point #2!

Comment: about step 2), Should I have two files(<app>.app and <app>.pkg) ?

Comment: It's not. I solved. the second <App>.pkg is what is going to be created. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to affect app review. If your archive is validated, you can just submit your app and it should work fine when downloaded from the app store.

Comment: Yes, but I like testing app before releasing it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1884](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1884/_index.html) document (dated 2015-01-26) covers this topic:

> *When I run my Mac app, it crashes immediately, and the crash log says Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid). What is going on here?*
>
> ... distribution builds of Mac apps cannot be run directly; they are for submitting to iTunes Connect for app review only.

The document suggests some work arounds.